# pip msgpack error while installing requirements

Tags: python, pip, msgpack, requirements.txt

I used `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and got this error:

`AttributeError: module 'msgpack' has no attribute 'dumps'`

Full log: https://pastebin.com/aTTwyrML

requirements.txt: https://github.com/poljar/weechat-matrix/blob/master/requirements.txt

This also seems to break other uses of `pip install`.

I can't find any `pip` issues or solutions to this anywhere.

EDIT: `msgpack` is being inmported from: `'/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py'`

Other packages that cause the error:

- `pytconf`

Comment: Do you have a file or folder called `msgpack` anywhere in your project?

Comment: @FlyingTeller No, I think it's just normal msgpack (local and system)

Comment: Can you open a python interpreter and do `import msgpack` followed by `msgpack.__file__` to check where it is being imported from?

Comment: Seems like this issue is fixed: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/issues/424

Answer (score 2):

You're running python version 3.8 and msgpack only supports up to 3.7. This might be causing a problem installing msgpack via pip or there's some breaking implementation in 3.8 that's not in 3.7 and under. I know I've run into some trouble with sharing projects between teams that are using 3.8 and teams that are using earlier verions.

[msgpack on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack-python/).